# Change certain column in text file, and the rest column will remain using batch script

Tags: batch-file

sorry if this silly questions,

I need to replace delimiter in text file column and data in certain column only.

I already success to replace delimiter from comma to pipe, but not yet on key in data.

THIS IS BATCH FOR REPLACE DELIMETER :

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set input="PLUIn.txt"
set output="dibalscopitems2.txt"

::There should be a TAB character after the equal below
set "tab=,"

>%output% (
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /rn "^" %input%') do (
set ln=%%A
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "ln=!ln:*:=!"
if defined ln set "ln=!ln:%tab%=|!"
echo(!ln!
endlocal
)
)
```

THE QUESTION IS :
For text file, i want to key in certain column only, and the rest column will auto generate.

As sample below :

Key in text file :
00001,1,7.50,APPLE,APPLE,0,0

Result after run batch :
M|00001|1|7.50|APPLE|APPLE|0|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|

So I only key in item in highlight on blue in images.
[Refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpHhU.png)

DETAILED COLUMN :

```
M|00001|1|7.50|AYAM SEGAR||0|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|
M|00002|2|6.99|APPLE||1|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|
M|00003|3|9.99|SIAKAP||1|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|
M|00004|4|1.99|ORANGE||1|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|
M|00005|5|12.99|KEMBUNG||0|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|
```

1. A,B @ M - A(add), B(Remove), M(modify)
2. Plu No - Max 6 digits
3. Hotkey - Max 3 digits
4. Unit price - 0.00
5. Name - 20 characters
6. Name2 - dummy
7. Weight unit - 0=weight / 1=pcs
8. Section (barcode structure no - 1=weight / 2=pcs
9. Label Format - dummy
10. EAN Format - dummy
11. Vat Type - dummy
12. Offer Price - dummy
13. Expiry Date - 001 = 1 days
14. Extra Date - dummy
15. Tare - dummy
16. EAN Scannner - dummy
17. Product Class - dummy
18. Product Direct Number - dummy
19. Overwrite Price - 0=allow / 1=notallow
20. G Text - dummy

INPUT FILES :

```
M,00001,1,7.50,AYAM SEGAR,,0,0,
M,00002,2,6.99,APPLE,,1,0,
M,00003,3,9.99,SIAKAP,,1,0,
M,00004,4,1.99,ORANGE,,1,0,
M,00005,5,12.99,KEMBUNG,,0,0,
```

RESULT AFTER RUN :

```
M|00001|1|7.50|AYAM SEGAR||0|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|
M|00002|2|6.99|APPLE||1|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|
M|00003|3|9.99|SIAKAP||1|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|
M|00004|4|1.99|ORANGE||1|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|
M|00005|5|12.99|KEMBUNG||0|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|
```

ON INPUT FILES,
we do not want to key in all column, as some column we do not use it.so from column no 9 until last, the values is not changed. we want to key in from column 1 until 8.

Thank you

Comment: sorry, for auto generate the rest of column, the data and values is same. nothing change.

Comment: Where are a sample data? Where are the example of the output? Do you want that we _enter_ the example data based on your image? **`:(`**  Post example data as text, not as an image!

Comment: @Aacini hi, this is sample data and result sir                                                     Key in text file : 00001,1,7.50,APPLE,APPLE,0,0

Result after run batch : M|00001|1|7.50|APPLE|APPLE|0|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|

Comment: The `|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|` inserted value is fixed and the same for all lines?

Comment: @Aacini inserted value is different, but auto generated value is fixed sir.

Comment: Again: where the `|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|` value in your example comes from? If I write a program I need to know how to generate such `|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|` string, isn't it?

Comment: @Aacini hi sir, actually this is exact format text file to transmit to scales, but we dont want our customer to key in all column as some column we do not use it,

Comment: Where is an example of the input file? Is it called "DETAILED COLUMN" like in your text or "PLUIn.txt" like in your code? Where the modification data comes from? From the keyboard? How many modification records can be entered? What happen if the mod record does not appear in the file?   Your question is not clear. You should describe the input data, explain the process to perform and show the output, but you have described the individual columns instead, that is information that have no relation with the process itself!!! If we have not clear what to do, we can't help you...

Comment: The "key in" (entered) data always replace the _first line_ (record) in the file? If not, how we know which line must be modified?

Comment: @Aacini hi sir, sorry if you not clear with my questions, we will input the data in PLUIn.txt and after run batch, it will save in dibalscopitems2.txt.  data we enter depends on customer database. i will modify the question to put example of input file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here we go...

**PLUIn.txt** the input file:

```
M,00001,1,7.50,AYAM SEGAR,,0,0,
M,00002,2,6.99,APPLE,,1,0,
M,00003,3,9.99,SIAKAP,,1,0,
M,00004,4,1.99,ORANGE,,1,0,
M,00005,5,12.99,KEMBUNG,,0,0,
```

The Batch file program:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "data=21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|"

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (PLUIn.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   echo !line:,=^|!!data!
)) > dibalscopitems2.txt
```

**dibalscopitems2.txt** the output file:

```
M|00001|1|7.50|AYAM SEGAR||0|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|
M|00002|2|6.99|APPLE||1|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|
M|00003|3|9.99|SIAKAP||1|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|
M|00004|4|1.99|ORANGE||1|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|
M|00005|5|12.99|KEMBUNG||0|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|
```

Some suggestions when you request technical aid:

You should describe your problem in terms as clear and concise as possible. Do **not** insert additional information not related to the problem that just could confuse! For example:

- Where is the input data?
- I want to key in certain column only
- Ok. How is such data?
- Because some column we do not use it, the rest column will auto generate.
- ("auto generate"? using which formula?) Ok, ok... I don't care if you want or want not to enter data, nor if you "key in" such a data or
  it magically appears in a file. Do you have a file with the data? How
  is it?

  M,00001,1,7.50,AYAM SEGAR,,0,0,
- And the output?

  M|00001|1|7.50|AYAM SEGAR||0|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|
- Ok. Thanks a lot!

**EDIT 2021/09/27**: *Modified program as requested in comment*

New **PLUIn.txt** input file:

```
M,00001,1,7.50,AYAM SEGAR,,0,0,1
M,00002,2,6.99,APPLE,,1,0,12
M,00003,3,9.99,SIAKAP,,1,0,123
M,00004,4,1.99,ORANGE,,1,0,555
M,00005,5,12.99,KEMBUNG,,0,0,999
```

New program.bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "data=|21|2|1|0.00|HERE|000|0||2|45|1|"

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (PLUIn.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a|"
   for /F "tokens=7* delims=," %%b in ("%%a") do (
      set "line=!line:,%%c|=!"
      echo !line:,=^|!!data:HERE=%%c!
   )
)) > dibalscopitems2.txt
```

New **dibalscopitems2.txt** output file:

```
M|00001|1|7.50|AYAM SEGAR||0|0|21|2|1|0.00|1|000|0||2|45|1|
M|00002|2|6.99|APPLE||1|0|21|2|1|0.00|12|000|0||2|45|1|
M|00003|3|9.99|SIAKAP||1|0|21|2|1|0.00|123|000|0||2|45|1|
M|00004|4|1.99|ORANGE||1|0|21|2|1|0.00|555|000|0||2|45|1|
M|00005|5|12.99|KEMBUNG||0|0|21|2|1|0.00|999|000|0||2|45|1|
```

Comment: hi sir, first of all, sorry about my mistake in asking questions, and for second things, thats code worked well !!.. thank you so much sir. But I have the last questions sir, on auto generated values, let say column in no 5 from this, "21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|" we need to use in input files, how to do it ? thanks in advanced.

Comment: Please, stop using "auto generated values" phrase! Such a term is used when a value is generated from another existent value. For example, if the existent data have an X value, an "auto generated value" could be "Y=3X+1" (a new value from old data: "auto generated" don't require additional data). Your `21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|` string is a _constant_ that do not depends on any other value! In a previous comment above I asked you if this value _"is fixed and the same for all lines"_. You should answer just "Yes", but your answer was totally incomprensible to me!

Comment: Sorry, but I have absolutely no idea what you tried to mean with "on auto generated values, let say column in no 5 from this, "21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|" we need to use in input files, how to do it ?" How to do what? Please, use concise and short words! Don't use terms like "auto generated value" nor "column no 5". What column 5? `21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|` is a _string_. Say something like "in the string change first `000` by `XYZ`". Please, help me to help you...

Comment: Yes, my mistake.. apologize sir.. I am trying to add one more column in input text file `M,00001,1,7.50,AYAM SEGAR,,0,0,999`  , the min to max digits is 0 - 999, but on string data, `21|2|1|0.00|**000**|000|0||2|45|1|`  ,its must put on string no 5 from left. actually i do not know how to elobrate it.but i will u give a full sample before and after. IINPUT FILE : `M,00001,1,7.50,AYAM SEGAR,,0,0,999`  OUTPUT FILE : `M|00001|1|7.50|AYAM SEGAR||0|0|21|2|1|0.00|999|000|0||2|45|1|`  like this sir. sorry for my weakness.

Comment: See the EDIT in my answer...

Comment: What happened with my new solution? It works? Also, I expect you upvote or select my answer as a retribution for the wotk I did...

Comment: hi sir, yes, your solutions is worked. thank you so much..i will select your answer as complete solutions. if not mind, how can we learn about this batch script for beginner?

Comment: hi sir, for last question, on input file, I need to remove M on first, and M value need to put in string. For Example Input File : `00001,1,7.50,AYAM SEGAR,,0,0,1` and Output file : `M|00001|1|7.50|AYAM SEGAR||0|0|21|2|1|0.00|1|000|0||2|45|1|`