# Need to replace value in fixed column on text file before convert in batch file

Tags: batch-file, command

I am successfully replace a value in text file by sequence,
but we need to jump to another column to to fill in new text file before convert.

this is original value in text file we need to fulfill, but some column is fixed, no need to change the data. so we use another text file using comma separator and convert it.

this is original fixed text file :
`M|00001|1|7.50|AYAM SEGAR||0|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|`

this is new text file using comma separator before convert :  `M,00001,1,7.50,AYAM SEGAR,,0,0,`

And this is command we use for converted :

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "data=21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|"

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (PLUIn.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   echo !line:,=^|!!data!
)) > dibalscopitems2.txt


timeout 1

call C:\Users\RCS\Desktop\Simple_Dibal_Kits\DibalPost.exe
```

But, we have to take another column in fixed column to fill in new text file before convert it.

from this original we need to add in new text file as we bold :
M|00001|1|7.50|AYAM SEGAR||0|0|21|2|1|0.00|**000**|000|0||2|45|**1**|

this new text file after add as bold below :
M,00001,1,7.50,AYAM SEGAR,,0,0,**000**,**1**,

how we can modify it in command to add this new column?

sorry if my question is quiet complicated to understand.

Comment: Why don't you take advantage of the `FOR /F` options: `TOKENS` and `DELIMS` to split the line into individual variables. Then you can output them in any order you want.  Just for clarity sake the pipe delimited file is not a fixed text file.  Fixed text mean each column as a specific length.  So if my name parts for first, middle and last were 15, 10 and 20 the data would look like: `JOSH               MICHAEL   JOHNSON             `. I work on mainframes. I deal with fixed text all day.

Comment: If this is a very large data file I would highly recommend you not use a batch file to accomplish this task.  Python would be a much better solution.

Comment: If you really do want to do this with pure batch a `FOR /F` command is not going to cut it because consecutive delimiters are seen as one field.  Which means you would need a pipe or csv file which has every field quote surrounded otherwise it will drop fields that have no data.  I would highly recommend you look at Dave Benahm's [ParseCSV.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5702). Contrary to its name you can parse any delimited file without worrying about the issues with the `FOR /F` commands limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your question is *very* complicated to understand because your explanations are very confusing...

In [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69308630/778560) I asked you to be very concise and clear, but you insist on inserting additional explanations unrelated to the problem that only complicate an otherwise simple description...

After read several times your question I *guess* that your new request could be described in these terms:

---

**Need to change a constant replaced value by a variable one**

I need to generate an output file with pipe-separated values taking as input a series of comma-separated values. For example, given this input file (PLUIn.txt):

```
M,00001,1,7.50,AYAM SEGAR,,0,0,
```

I currently generate this output file (dibalscopitems2.txt):

```
M|00001|1|7.50|AYAM SEGAR||0|0|21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|
```

That is, replace commas by pipe and insert `21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|` constant data at end. This is currently achieved via this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "data=21|2|1|0.00|000|000|0||2|45|1|"

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (PLUIn.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   echo !line:,=^|!!data!
)) > dibalscopitems2.txt
```

Now I need to do this change: the inserted data will be no longer constant, but the output columns marked with **bold** text:

M|00001|1|7.50|AYAM SEGAR||0|0|21|2|1|0.00|**000**|000|0||2|45|**1**|

... needs to be taken from the input file at these positions:

M,00001,1,7.50,AYAM SEGAR,,0,0,**000**,**1**,

How can I modify the code to do that?

---

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "data=21|2|1|0.00|XXX|000|0||2|45|YYY|"

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (PLUIn.txt) do for /F "tokens=8,9 delims=," %%x in ("%%a") do (
   set "line=%%a"
   set "line=!line:%%x,%%y,=!"
   set "out=!data:XXX=%%x!"
   echo !line:,=^|!!out:YYY=%%y!
)) > dibalscopitems2.txt
```

As you can see, this method is *exactly the same* of my last answer in [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69308630/778560).